# How to ping remote host with jump

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, ping

suppose that I have this situation:

[image: Layout with three machines: "host", "jumphost", "server", machines are only connected through "jumphost"]

How can I from `host` ping `Server`? Important information is that, `Server` is visible only for `JumpHost`.
`host` and `Server` are Linux-based, but `JumpHost` is a Windows, and I would like to avoid scripting on the Windows platform.

Comment: Did you try to ping it? Ping isn't OS specific. What error did you see when you ping server from host?

Comment: yes i know that, but "ping" command is part of whole script and i as i mentioned i do not want script in windows

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. What difference does it make whether you can ping or not?

Comment: By "visible only for jumphost" i mean that "server" is placed in local address space of Jumphost. It mean that server adress is 192.168.100.3. The same addres on "host" mean different connetion. Server is not visible for "host"

Comment: I have idea about some ssh tunnel but i do not know is this is proper way of work and probably there exist more sufficient solution for this kind of problem

Comment: But what exactly is the problem? `ping` is just a *diagnostic* tool. By making it work in some non-standard way between these machines you don't necessarily make anything else work. Do you need `ping` to work because some software refuses to work without being able to literally ping the server? Or do you need some *other* service to work?

Comment: From your comments, I'm wondering that you might want to run some bash script from host that involves commands that require ip connectivity from `host` to `Server`. You will either need IP connectivity (maybe via a VPN or enable routing host to Server IP spaces in Jumphost) or change the script enough so that you don't need IP connectivity. You may not want to do that, it's a bit unclear what you are asking, please rephrase and explain your question so that it's useful to you and to future others that come looking for the same thing.

Comment: @ssice please see my answer

Comment: Are `host` and `server` on separate physical network media?  Or do they merely have different address spaces (ranges) on networks that electrically connect?  If the latter, you could add the other network to the device on `host`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the command as an argument. e.g. Let's say your jump server is `JUMP` and the remote host is `HOST`. Just do:

```
ssh JUMP "ping -c 1 HOST"
```

In the format:

```
ssh <USER>@<JUMP_SERVER> <CMD>
```

Comment: I think that, in general, to execute a command on a server through a jump host through ssh, the command looks like this:`ssh -i /key/to/jump -J jump_user@jumphost -i /key/to/server server_user@server <command>`.